# BlackBerry forcefully interupt the facebook connect

Tags: facebook, blackberry

I am using the following method to share my app data
but if the user clicks back on the main screen, I would like it to forcefully close facebook connect.

```
public class FacebookIntegration {

    private static User user;
    private static String NEXT_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
    private static String APPLICATION_ID ;
    private static String APPLICATION_SECRET ;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS = Facebook.Permissions.USER_DATA_PERMISSIONS;
    public static boolean posted = false;
    private static String[] postPermissions = Facebook.Permissions.PUBLISHING_PERMISSIONS;
    private static SharePopup _obj;
    private static boolean exception = false;

    public static boolean integrate(SharePopup obj) {

        _obj = obj;
        ApplicationSettings as = new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, PERMISSIONS);
        ApplicationSettings as2 = new ApplicationSettings(null, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, PERMISSIONS);

        Facebook fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);

         _obj.close();
        try {
            user = fb.getCurrentUser();
        } catch (FacebookException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
            exception = true;
        }
        if (!exception) {
            try {

                fb.getCurrentUser(new BasicAsyncCallback() {
                    public void onComplete(com.blackberry.facebook.inf.Object[] objects, final java.lang.Object state) {
                        FacebookIntegration.this.user = (User) objects[0];
                        Vector prayerTimes = (Vector) PrayerTimesDTO.getPrayerTimes();
                        StringBuffer post = new StringBuffer("avbc");

                        user.publishStatus(post.toString());

                        posted = true;

                        user.publishPost("stream.publish", "published through the Facebook API", APPLICATION_SECRET, null, null, null, user.getId());

                    }

                    public void onException(final Exception e, final java.lang.Object state) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                });

            } catch (FacebookException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                fb.logout(true);


            }
        }
        return true;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been pondering this since you first posted it. I don't think anyone can help you because we would have to know what the Facebook object does. That is probly where you will have to close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

A. In your MainScreen class override the onClose function:

```
public boolean onClose() {
     FacebookIntegration.closeConnection(); 
     return super.onClose();
}
```

B. Change `FacebookIntegration` as follows:

1. Put Facebook object as static field in the class

   `private static Facebook fb;`
2. Change the line of: `Facebook fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);` 
   to be `fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);`
3. Add the `closeConnection` method to `FacebookIntegration` as follows:

   `public static void closeConnection() {
         fb.logout(true); 
   }`

Comment: but i want to logout once it has logged in not logout it every time on screen close.. how will i get that done ??

Comment: When the user clicks back on mainscreen (as in your scenario), the OS fires the onClose() method

Comment: @AshrafBashir, Can you please give me some sample you have done Blackberry+Facebook SDK. please pass to nilanchala@outlook.com. also see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962248/facebook-oauth-implementation-for-blackberry